Question about proving that $c_0\subset l^\infty$ doesn't have a topological complement
I was assigned a homework problem to prove that the space $c_0\subset l^\infty$ where $l^\infty$ is the set of bounded sequences in $\mathbb{C}$ doesn't have a topological complement. I've attached the problem below.

I've proved part $(a)$ and $(b)$, but failed to prove part $(c)$. Here is my progress:
Suppose that $L_n(\varphi)\rightarrow 0$ for every $\varphi$, then by UBP $||L_n|| < C$ for some number $C$, hence we can find characteristic functions as described by part $(b)$. Let $\varphi$ be the characteristic function as described in the hint, i.e. $\varphi$ is the characteristic function on a sequence $a = (a_n)$ in natural numbers where $\phi_n(a_n) = 1$ for every $n$. I don't know how to proceed next.
I probably need to prove that if $L_n(\varphi)\rightarrow 0$, this contradicts with part $(b)$. But I don't know why. If $L_n(\varphi)\rightarrow 0$, $||\varphi_nL_n||$ can still be very small right? My only observation is that $\varphi_n\varphi$ is the characteristic function of a singleton set for every $n$, but I don't know whether this will be useful.
I also can't think of how to prove part $(d)$ assuming the correctness of part $(c)$. If $c_0$ has a topological complement, then every sequence $u$ can be uniquely decomposed as a sequence $u_1\in c_0$ and $u_2$ in the complement. I can't proceed anymore.
Any hint or help is welcome!
